# locationManager:didExitRegion: a big delay of firing when transmitting is stopped

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I'm working on the app that monitors CLBeaconRegion and present local notifications to the user when he enter/exits region. Everything works fine, but while testing I spot that if I enter region, got call of locationManager:didEnterRegion: and then turn off transmitting beacon, I got call of locationManager:didExitRegion: only in about 2 minutes.

Could anyone help to avoid this delay?

Transmitting device is iPhone 4s with iOS 8.3. Receiving device is iPhone 4s with iOS 7.1.2

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    ...
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an app is in the background on a 4S (or if it is in the foreground and not ranging) it can take up to 15 minutes to get a `didEnterRegion` callback.  **A `didExitRegion` callback can take 15 minutes and 3 seconds.**

Why?  Because the 4S only scans for beacons every 15 minutes in the background to save battery.  And only after 3 seconds of not seeing a beacon do you get a `didExitRegion` event.

See here for details: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html

**EDIT:**  You can make your device detect more quickly in the foreground by enabling ranging at the same as you enable monitoring.  Simply call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` after you call `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion:`

Newer iOS devices iPhone 5+ have hardware assist that scans constantly in the background and in the foreground when not ranging, but the slots for this assist are limited.  Only the first 30 registered regions get access to this fast background detection, and again, this is not available on the 4S.

Comment: But App is running in the foreground for testing purpose.

Comment: See my edited answer.  The problem also applies to the foreground if you are monitoring but not ranging.